# WSO2 Identity Server 5.10.0 - Unable to achieve EmailOTP based MFA

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have enabled EmailOTP Identity Provider, using WSO2 Identity Server as Email Provider.

In my Service PRovider, I have enabled EmailOTP as the second step of Authentication.

Angular UI application is my front end, when I provide username/password on the login page (user OpenId Connect), the authorization code is getting generated, but the second step is not being invoked, i.e., OTP page is not being displayed and Email is not being sent to the recipient with OTP.

I have followed the steps mentioned here, except making Gmail as Identity Provider.

OpenIdConnect Configuration:

[image]

Local and Outbound Authentication Configuration:

[image]

EmailOTP IDP Configuration (did not use Gmail or SendGrid):

[image]

EMail Adapter and Authenticator Configuration:

```
[output_adapter.email]
from_address= "sender@domain.com"
username= "username@domain.com"
password= "password"
hostname= "smpt.hostname"
port= 25
enable_start_tls= false
enable_authentication= true

[authentication.authenticator.basic.parameters]
showAuthFailureReason = true

[authentication.authenticator.email_otp]
name ="EmailOTP"
enable=true

[authentication.authenticator.email_otp.parameters]
EMAILOTPAuthenticationEndpointURL = "https://10.201.8.13:5004/emailotpauthenticationendpoint/emailotp.jsp"
EmailOTPAuthenticationEndpointErrorPage = "https://10.201.8.13:5004/emailotpauthenticationendpoint/emailotpError.jsp"
EmailAddressRequestPage = "https://10.201.8.13:5004/emailotpauthenticationendpoint/emailAddress.jsp"
usecase = "local"
secondaryUserstore = "primary"
EMAILOTPMandatory = false
sendOTPToFederatedEmailAttribute = false
federatedEmailAttributeKey = "email"
EmailOTPEnableByUserClaim = true
CaptureAndUpdateEmailAddress = true
showEmailAddressInUI = true
useEventHandlerBasedEmailSender = true
```

Script based authentication Configuration:

```
var onLoginRequest = function(context) {
    executeStep(1);
    executeStep(2);
};
```

OpenId Connect Configuration.

[image]
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/learn/configuring-email-otp/#configuring-email-otp

Endpoint details:

```
https://localhost:5004/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&scope=openid&redirect_uri=http://localhost&client_id=<client_id>&code_challenge=<code_challenge>&code_challenge_method=S256&sectoken=<sec_token>
```

**Tenant Domain Error:**

The tenant domain user is being treated as a user of carbon.super domain.

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-01 17:13:47,683] [85d31877-3090-4139-9efb-d40f85c2e2eb] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.emailotp.EmailOTPAuthenticator}
    - OTP Expiration Time not specified default value will be used
 TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-01 17:13:47,684] [85d31877-3090-4139-9efb-d40f85c2e2eb] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator}
    - Exception in Authentication Framework java.lang.NullPointerException
                at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.AbstractApplicationAuthenticator.publishAuthenticationStepAttempt(AbstractApplicationAuthenticator.java:170)
                at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.AbstractApplicationAuthenticator.process(AbstractApplicationAuthenticator.java:94)
                at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.emailotp.EmailOTPAuthenticator.process(EmailOTPAuthenticator.java:139)
                at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler.doAuthentication(DefaultStepHandler.java:506)
                at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler.handleResponse(DefaultStepHandler.java:480)
                at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler.handle(DefaultStepHandler.java:179)
                at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.sequence.impl.DefaultStepBasedSequenceHandler.handle(DefaultStepBasedSequenceHandler.java:185) er} - 
Error occurred while getting claims for user: tanoj123@carbon.super from userstore. org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: 30007 - UserNotFound: 
User tanoj123 does not exist in: PRIMARY
            at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.callSecure(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:205)
            at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.getUserClaimValues(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:1758)
            at org.wso2.carbon.identity.openidconnect.DefaultOIDCClaimsCallbackHandler.getUserClaimsInLocalDialect(DefaultOIDCClaimsCallbackHandler.java:466)
            at org.wso2.carbon.identity.openidconnect.DefaultOIDCClaimsCallbackHandler.getUserClaimsInOIDCDialect(DefaultOIDCClaimsCallbackHandler.java:420)
            at org.wso2.carbon.identity.openidconnect.DefaultOIDCClaimsCallbackHandler.retrieveClaimsForLocalUser(DefaultOIDCClaimsCallbackHandler.java:296)
            at org.wso2.carbon.identity.openidconnect.DefaultOIDCClaimsCallbackHandler.getUserClaimsInOIDCDialect(DefaultOIDCClaimsCallbackHandler.java:146)
            at org.wso2.carbon.identity.openidconnect.DefaultOIDCClaimsCallbackHandler.handleCustomClaims(DefaultOIDCClaimsCallbackHandler.java:85)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.token.APIMJWTGenerator.populateCustomClaims_aroundBody4(APIMJWTGenerator.java:166)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.token.APIMJWTGenerator.populateCustomClaims(APIMJWTGenerator.java:156)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.token.APIMJWTGenerator.buildBody_aroundBody2(APIMJWTGenerator.java:95)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.token.APIMJWTGenerator.buildBody(APIMJWTGenerator.java:92)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.token.APIMJWTGenerator.generateJWT_aroundBody0(APIMJWTGenerator.java:69)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.token.APIMJWTGenerator.generateJWT(APIMJWTGenerator.java:60)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.util.APIMTokenIssuerUtil.generateToken_aroundBody4(APIMTokenIssuerUtil.java:210)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.util.APIMTokenIssuerUtil.generateToken(APIMTokenIssuerUtil.java:173)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.issuers.APIMTokenIssuer.accessToken_aroundBody0(APIMTokenIssuer.java:102)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.issuers.APIMTokenIssuer.accessToken(APIMTokenIssuer.java:51)
            at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler.getNewAccessToken(AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler.java:491)
            at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler.createNewTokenBean(AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler.java:390)
            at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler.generateNewAccessToken(AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler.java:344)
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your Authentication Step Configurations?

Comment: And if there any error logs, please provide.

Comment: @sumedhe - I have added the screenshots. I am not getting any errors but the Email OTP Page is not loading or getting redirected to from Angular Application.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the adaptive authentication script section on the advanced configurations page?

Comment: @MadurangaSiriwardena - I have added the code/scripts for the same, in the question.

Comment: According to your configs, the EmailOTP step can be skipped if the `http://wso2.org/claims/identity/emailotp_disabled` claim is set to `true` for this particular user.

Comment: If it is not the case, let's enable debug logs and see.

Open log4j2.properties file.

Uncomment the two lines starting with `logger.org-wso2-carbon-identity-application-authentication-framework`

Add following two lines
`logger.org-wso2-carbon-identity-authenticator-emailotp.name=org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.emailotp
logger.org-wso2-carbon-identity-authenticator-emailotp.level=DEBUG`

Add `, org-wso2-carbon-identity-application-authentication-framework, org-wso2-carbon-identity-authenticator-emailotp` to the end of the line starting with `loggers =`

Comment: Can you give it a try with `EmailOTPEnableByUserClaim` set to false?

Comment: @MadurangaSiriwardena It did not work even after the change.

Comment: @Sajith - I have made the changes, but not getting any logs triggered for Email OTP flow.

Comment: @Sajith - When I remove "Request Path Authentication Configuration", it loads the WSO2 Login page for the first step and then redirecting to the EMail OTP page as the second step. Whereas, when I enable "Request Path Authentication Configuration" with "BasicAuthRequestPathAuthenticator", it doesn't load EmailOTP page.

Comment: @MadurangaSiriwardena - Please look at my previous comment.

Comment: @PrabakaranThodithotSembiyan, I tried enabling the BasicAuthRequestPathAuthenticator, but I couldn't see your issue. If I use the log4j2 as https://pastebin.com/ewEZutgM, I can find the debug logs as in https://pastebin.com/neUEyHR8 after username-password is submitted. You can compare the same in your setup.

Comment: @Sajith - I have also enabled the same logs, but with OpenId Connet configuration I'm unable to receive any logs or email. I am using IS-Km (not plain IS)

Comment: @Sajith - We have enabled "PKCE Mandatory" and "Allow authentication without the client secret". Should I disable this?

Comment: No, it should not have an effect on this. Since you got it working fine with request path authenticator disabled, there should a relation with it. Still, you should get enough debug logs by using log4j2 as pastebin.com/ewEZutgM for IS-KM 5.10.0 as well to identify the cause.

Comment: Btw, are you using the wso2 login page (authenticationendpoint) or a login page on your Angular UI?

Comment: I'm using login page on Angular UI. I am not getting any logs for Email OTP steps even if the debug logs are enabled.  When I remove request path authentication, I get the debug logs. @Sajith

Comment: We enable debug logs to trace the case for issue, not to fix it :)

Comment: What is the request/endpoint you are using to pass the username & password to WSO2 IS?

Comment: We are passing the request to /oauth2/authorize endpoint. Added sample in question. @Sajith

Comment: FYI, My IS is running on 5004 instead of 9443.

Comment: @Sajith - I have added debug logs here https://pastebin.com/SEeveDHB and here https://pastebin.com/FTKHEPWD

Comment: I can see from thr logs that the “Step based authentication” is not getting triggered when I use Basic Request Path Authentication. @sajith

Comment: Got it, thanks. please check the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the shared logs, the following line can be observed.

```
BasicAuthRequestPathAuthenticator can handle the request
```

It means `canHandle()` method of the [BasicAuthRequestPathAuthenticator](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-outbound-auth-requestpath-basicauth/blob/master/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.requestpath.basicauth/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/application/authenticator/requestpath/basicauth/BasicAuthRequestPathAuthenticator.java) has returned `true` since `sectoken` query parameter is defined. Then, the request path authentication has taken place.

[BasicAuth RequestPathAuthentication](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/basic-auth-request-path-authentication/) does not support MFA and it is like the password grant. The user gets authenticated by just validating the passed credentials.

If your goal is to have the login page on your client application (Angular SPA), you can pass the username and password as two different parameters (POST OR GET; POST is recommended since the password will not be passed in the URL) in the `oauth2/authorize` request and get into the default basic authenticator instead of the RequestPathAuthenticator. Then MFA will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks @Sajith I have used the same option you suggested and it works fine.

Comment: Hi @Sajith, This Email OTP scenario works fine for carbon.super domain users but failing for tenant domain users. After giving OTP, it is resulting in the error I mentioned in the question, under the "Tenant Domain Error" section. Can you please let me know what to do here.

Comment: IS is unable to provide the requested claims back to the user

Comment: To add more, the emailotp.jsp page is loading with tenantDomain as carbon.super and while submitting the otp also it is goung as carbon.super instead of the actual tenant domain. How can it take the domain name from the first step of authentication?

Comment: Email OTP authenticator does not make use of the tenantDomain query param to decide on the user's tenant. Instead it derives it using the information stored in the context from the previous step.

What kind of authentication is done in the 1st step?

Comment: We are using "basic" as the Local Authenticator in the 1st step.  But as per the logs, I can see the tenant domain user is being considered as carbon.super domain user (as in the logs provided)

Comment: What happens if you append the tenant domain to the end of username?

Comment: I'm already sending the username as username@tenantdomain